# Google API How to identify primary Calendar

Tags: api, calendar

In my application, I need to export to primary Google calendar. In my testing the calendar query seems to always return the default/primary calendar as the first entry in the array, but this is never mentioned in the documentation so likely not guaranteed.

I also notice that the calendar title is sometimes user@domain.com even though the primary calendar title in UI is often in the "First Last" format. I believe this only happens if the user does not override the name. Is this a bug?

In other instances the calendar title is "First Last" and not the email or some other custom name. Is there a reliable way to identify a primary calendar, or should I take the first item in array and hope that it never changes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use 'primary' to identify the primary calendar.
It works fine for me in php and JAVA. Or identify with the calendar id, that should be the owner's email.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer seems to be that a primary Calendar can always be identified by the feed:
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full/username%40domain.com, so the lookup is not necessary. There's lack of documentation in this area and some inconsistency in the way the title is populated for primary calendars that had not been re-named by the users.